# How to record or log telnet session using the command line?

Tags: linux, unix, telnet

I need to record the output of a telnet session.

I can't just pipe or output it because I need to authenticate first.

How I can achieve this log?

Answer (score 4):

First run 'script' and specify the log file

```
script mylogfile.log
```

Then a new bash session is initialized and all you need to do is run telnet.

When you're done just quit telnet, and type exit to stop recording. All the output will be in mylogfile.log

Comment: /usr/bin/script makes files that are full of control characters, like tabs, backspaces, and carriage returns, and a program like 'tr' or 'sed' may have to be used to get rid of 'em.
(This looks crappy, and should be in an answer...)

tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < mylogfile.log > mycleanfile.log

Comment: Note: use `exit` to exit the script session and close your `mylogfile.log`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do what you want with 'tee'

```
telnet HOST | tee -i session-recording.log
```

You still can login and your password will not display in the recording.

Comment: Unfortunately, in MSYS2, this will make it impossible to break out of/exit `telnet` with the usual Ctrl+] - so you'll have to `kill` `telnet` from another MSYS2 terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use gnu screen as a telnet client to do this:

With gnu screen version 4.05.01 or later, you can specify the log file name on the command line:
`screen -L -Logfile session.txt //telnet 10.10.0.10 23`

This will log a telnet session with 10.10.0.10:23 to session.txt - The port number is for illustration only, and not actually needed if you're on the standard port 23.

You can also turn on/off logging while the session is in progress.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240796/gnu-screen-how-to-enable-or-disable-logging-while-screen-is-already-attached

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning the earliest GNU Screen version which supports it. Looks like it's `4.06.02`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48614247/1025073

Comment: Going through the git history of gnu screen, it looks like this feature may have been available since version 3.9.4. See: https://github.com/shyouhei/screen/commit/e6618a14fab6b993f328373d4180d32452d761b4 (search for 'telnet')

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then version `4.01.000devel (GNU) 2-May-06` on CentOS 7.9.2009 is built without it: `Error: Unknown option Logfile`.

Comment: PS. Now I see I was too implicit, please excuse me. I mean namely the `-Logfile` option.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  Looking through the source - it seems 4.05.01 is the minimum version which allows the given invocation to enable logging.  It should be possible in 4.05.00 with the slightly different invocation 'screen -L file.txt ...' which according to source will set the log name AND enable logging.  I have not actually tried this though.  Previous versions, you _may_ be able to set a logfile name in .screenrc and enable logging with -L

Comment: Thank you for the digging in! Even in case these versions aren't exact, it would be much easier for the user to get a clue or two about what version upgrade one needs to perform. Cheers!